# Can class file be created even if .java file is not compiled?

Tags: java

My code is this:

```
public class try1 {     
    public static void main(String[] arg){  
        System.out.print("in main\n");

        try{
            ablurt( "An exception will occur" );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.print("exception occured--"+e);
        }
        finally{
            System.out.print("I'm always here");
        }
    }  
}
```

my question is , if i try to run this code using netbeans IDE, class file is created and it gives run time error.
but if i try to run it on on cmd , it is compile time error, and class file is also not created

why different behaviour of same program?

Comment: What kind of compile time error?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't see ablurt anywhere

Comment: on cmd it says that alburt is not defined,

Comment: and on netbeans it says java.lang.RunTimeException-uncompilable source code -Errenous Sym type:Alburt I'am always there

Comment: Are you actually compiling on cmd or just running a class file?  You have to use "javac" to compile and "java" to run.  Either way, if you have an error, it won't run.  What is the compile error?

Comment: my question is why it creates .class file in case of netbeans but not in case of cmd

Comment: i am trying to compile on cmd

Comment: Where is ablurt defined?  This will never compile if that is not defined.  The .class file may not necessarily be complete when created from Netbeans.

Comment: Eclipse has  had this "feature" for some time.  It's a very bad idea IMHO as it allows you to routinely ignore compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Netbeans, but what [Eclipse does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394152/how-can-eclipse-create-a-class-with-unresolved-compilation-problems) with source files with compilation error is to actually compile a modified version of a class which throws an `Error`. I assume this is what Netbeans does, too.